# In Enterprise Architect What does it mean if the package icon has a red one?

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have a remote repository in postgres which is accessed by ODBC, no process or permission is blocked, but some time ago one of the packages appears with a red mark, as shown below

[image: package icon has a red one]

Comment: Either it's a name space root or it's set to VC. Can't remember since I use neither and it's too long ago I did...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means this package is marked as a namespace root.
You can set this property using the option
**Develop | Source Code | Options | Set Package as Namespace Root**
[image]

See [the manual](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_repositories/ref_data_namespaces.html) for more details

Comment: My memory doesn't seem to be too bad ;-)